No logro actualizar Picker en .net MAUI con codigo de barras
Tengo una app para Android programada en .NET MAUI, y al leer un codigo de barras me toma el texto correctamente pero no actualiza un Picker que tengo con productos, es decir el cliente puede seleccionar del Picker o directamente escanear el codigo de barras:
   public ObservableCollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }

   private Producto _productoSeleccionado;
   public Producto ProductoSeleccionado
   {
       get => _productoSeleccionado;
       set
       {
           if (_productoSeleccionado != value)
           {
               _productoSeleccionado = value;
               OnPropertyChanged(); // Notifica cambios
           }
       }
   }

El codigo de arriba es el Observable y el atributo producto en cuestión, estees el xaml del picker:

 <!-- Picker para Selección de Productos -->
 <Picker x:Name="productosPicker"
Title="Seleccionar productos"
TitleColor="Black"
FontAttributes="Bold"
BackgroundColor="LightGray"
TextColor="Black"
ItemsSource="{Binding Productos}"
ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding producto}"
SelectedIndexChanged="OnEventIndexChanged"
SelectedItem="{Binding ProductoSeleccionado}" />


Aquí debajo dejo el método, que dado que se escanea en otra ContentPage uso el sistema de mensajería de MAUI:
     MessagingCenter.Subscribe<QRCP, QrScanned>(this, "QrScanned", async (sender, mensaje) =>
     {
         string qrTexto = mensaje.CodigoQr;
         string idTarea = mensaje.Tarea;
        
         var productos = await _viewModel.ObtenerProductosPorTarea(idTarea);

 /*        if (productos != null)
         {
             // Mostrar el código QR escaneado
             await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Código QR Escaneado",productos.Count().ToString(), "OK");

             // Mostrar cada ID de producto para comparar
             foreach (var producto in productos)
             {
                 await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Producto en lista", $"ID Producto: {producto.id}", "OK");
             }
         }*/

         // Buscar el producto cuyo ID coincide con el texto escaneado
         var productoEncontrado = productos.FirstOrDefault(p => p.codigo.Trim() == qrTexto.Trim());

         if (productoEncontrado != null)
         {
             _viewModel.ProductoSeleccionado = null;
             _viewModel.ProductoSeleccionado = productoEncontrado;
         }
         else
         {
             await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Producto no encontrado", "No se encontró ningún producto con el código escaneado.", "OK");
         }
     });

como verán en el código comentado ya me asegure que estoy trayendo los artículos a partir de la tarea, luego lo filtro y funciona todo, no entiendo porque no lo selecciona.
